# Can't send birthday gifts or greetings on geni.com

Tags: geni.com

Sometimes when I try to send a birthday greeting or write on someone's guestbook, I get the message:

> You can't send a birthday greeting to this person

How can I fix this issue? Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

I've not got an account but from reading their privacy statement:

> - You can block individual relatives from viewing your individual profile or messaging you.
> - You can further restrict what information appears on your profile in your account settings.

It could be that that person has blocked messages from you or further restricted their settings (which I can't view as I'm not a member).